# Script disables some components on my table

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how my webpage looks like:
[image]

As can be seen in the picture I have I have search on the top right, in the bottom right I have the amount of pages etc..

But as I add another project here by clicking "Lägg till ny" and add a project for some reason my page will end up like this:
http://puu.sh/kKSZz/387c71f487.png

As can be seen the table "Breaks" the search field gets removed and so does the pages. Same things happens when I chose to edit or delete a project I've already added.

This is my view:

```
<div id="tabs-current">
<div id="ConsultantTimes">
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("ConsulantTimes");
    }
</div>
    <a href="javascript:OpenDialog()" class="btn btn-primary">
        Lägg till ny
    </a>
</div>
```

As can be seen the table is a partial view and here it is:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Projekt</th>
        <th>Mitt Datum</th>
        <th>%</th>
        <th>Projektdatum</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var project in ViewData["times"] as List<ConsultantProjectTime>)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:OpenDialog2('@project.ID','@project.FK_ProjectID','@project.StartDate.ToShortDateString()','@project.EndDate.ToShortDateString()','@project.Pct');">
                    @project.Project.ProjectName
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>@(project.StartDate.ToShortDateString() + " - " + project.EndDate.ToShortDateString())</td>
            <td>@(project.Pct)%</td>
            <td>
                @if (project.Project.StartDate.HasValue && project.Project.EndDate.HasValue)
                {
                    @(project.Project.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + " - " + project.Project.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

And this is my script I run when I choose to add another project:

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 220,
        width: 305,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Spara': function() {

                if (!validate()) {
                    alert('Procent måste vara mellan 0-100');
                    return false;
                }

                locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Update/?";

                locstring += '&projectId=' + $('#projectList').val();
                locstring += '&startDate=' + $('#startDate').val();
                locstring += '&endDate=' + $('#endDate').val();
                locstring += '&pct=' + $('#pct').val();

                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid != "") {
                    locstring += '&id=' + sid;
                    //locstring = "/Delete/" + sid;
                }
                //window.location = locstring;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: locstring,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //alert(locstring);
                        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        ReloadTable();
                    }
                });


            },
            'Avbryt': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Ta bort': function() {
                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid != "") {
                    locstring = "@(Url.Action("Index"))/Delete/" + sid;
                    //locstring += '&delete=true&id=' + sid;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: locstring,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                            ReloadTable();
                        }
                    });
```

**Note, when this happends I have no errors in my console.**

Found the error but not sure how to solve it, it's my ReloadTable function:

```
        function ReloadTable() {
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            //alert('suck..');
            window.location.reload();
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@(Url.Action("ConsulantTimes"))',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                    $('#ConsultantTimes').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What gets disabled exactly?

Comment: Well, not disabled but removed. If you compare the two pictures my Search in the top right, my page count in the bottom right and the amount of entries i want to show.

Comment: Found the error, but I am not sure how to solve it, it's my reload table function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is replacing the entire contents of `#ConsultantTimes` and replacing it with the `data` variable. Use `$( "sample_1" ).replaceWith(data);` instead, or maybe prepend or append.

Comment: Than it does not break, the visual stuff are still there but they stop working. Weird.

Comment: When you are using selectors in jquery, they only work for elements that exist when the page is loaded. Any DOM (html) changes will not be counted in selectors. Use the `.on` feature to counteract this. http://api.jquery.com/on/